Is the idiom "the dog's bollocks" acceptable for printed media?
We are writing a book on idioms for university students who study linguistics. Can we use the idiom "the dog's bollocks (=ace, brill, etc.)" in it?
I personally like this idiom and find it quite interesting but the dictionary warns that it is very rude.
Very rude is how much rude? As rude as dirty English or using it in a book seems ok?

If you don't understand how/when the idiom is used, and the tone it has when used, what are you going to say about it in your book on idioms?

It's the word "bollocks" that's rude. It's a swear word. It literally means "testicles".  On the scale of offensiveness, it's about as rude as saying "shit".  So, it's not hugely rude, but it's not something I would say in polite company, or use in formal English.

We have taken this idiom from the book called "A really British guide to English" which explains how to use this idiom. It says: rude way to say brilliant or fantastic (synonym for mutt's nuts) and gives an example.

Well, there's your answer.  Yes, it's rude.  It could offend someone.  "nuts" is also slang for "testicles", and "mutt" is slang for a dog, a mongrel especially.

While testing the book, a student pointed to this fact that it us rude and I asked myself a question: "How much rude is it then? Rude enough not be used in books? Then why did the book print it? " And I decided to ask you, native speakees.

Now I understand. Thanks a lot!

I've already told you it's rude, and how rude it is.  Books can contain rude language.   There's no law against it, if you like those kind of books!

You mention that it is for students of linguistics. You can be as rude as you like if the subject is sociolinguistics.  But if the focus of the book is a practical guide to conversation (not really "linguistics") you need to be explicit about the contexts in which that idiom is used.  It sounds a lot ruder to me (AmE speaker) than "the cat's meow".

Hi, TimR, is "the cat's meow" applicable to a person? Just for me to know.

[correction: How rude is it? No much.] The term you should include is just "Bollocks", which is used as an interjection in response to something someone says. In any case, who cares if it's rude if you are compiling idioms?? You are not writing them...

@Avidlearner  "The cat's meow" can be used of persons.  She thinks she's the cat's meow.

If the text is aimed at "students of linguistics", you should at least refer to the original versions of this idiomatic construction There was a craze for it in the US in the 1920s, at which time elephant’s adenoids, cat’s miaow, ant’s pants, tiger’s spots, bullfrog’s beard and many similar forms were doing the rounds, but only the bees knees and the cat's pyjamas have really survived. See my answer on ELU, where I said BrE dog's bollocks was unrelated (ours got a massive revival in the 70s from Viz magazine).

Modern general-purpose dictionaries and other similar reference works don't censor their entries. For example, Collins has your exact idiom. (All bets are off for specialized reference works; I would not expect to see profanity in a children's dictionary or something documenting formal, technical vocabulary.)
Older works censored the worst words. For example, most editions of Grose's Dictionary of the Vulgar Tongue had entries like "**** hooks" (with no indication the missing word is "cunt"). Other works (e.g., 1st edition OED) omitted such words entirely, as if they didn't exist. Publishers were forced to do this because of censorship laws at the time in Britain.
Assuming you're not publishing under similar rules, there's no reason to censor your book.

I would say they are not "writing a book". They are compiling existing an alphabetical list of idioms.

@Lambie We don't know that. A book on idioms would likely include more than a definition for each term (i.e., extended discussion), and it may not even be alphabetical.

Normally, we'd say a dictionary of idioms. Like these: https://www.google.com/search?q=dictionary+of+idioms&rlz=1C1GCEU_enUS1077US1078&oq=dictionary+of+idi&gs_lcrp=EgZjaHJvbWUqBwgAEAAYgAQyBwgAEAAYgAQyBwgBEAAYgAQyBggCEEUYOTIHCAMQABiABDIHCAQQABiABDIHCAUQABiABDINCAYQABiGAxiABBiKBTINCAcQABiGAxiABBiKBTIKCAgQABiABBiiBDIKCAkQABiABBiiBKgCCLACAQ&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8 OR it may just be a glossary.

300+ pages. With texts, exercises, history of creation where we can trace it, etc.

Asking if the phrase is acceptable for print is really no different to asking if it is acceptable to say it out loud - clearly some people do say it, but it is considered rude by some.
It certainly is already in print - Google Books returns plenty of results, the first of which is a compendium of British 'adult' humour comic Viz titled 'Viz: The Dog's Bollocks' back in 1989, but for context, the periodical comic is normally placed on the 'top shelf' on newsstands indicating that it is for an adult audience.
Cambridge Dictionary currently marks the word 'bollocks' as "offensive", which is subjective, but a general guide to suggest that you ought not use it in a 'mixed' audience, or polite company.

If a group of people are friends and having dinner together and someone says something, another person might very well say "Bollocks! I think etc.".  It's very conversational unless you have some formal meeting with someone...

Thank you all for your answers. Have a nice day to you all!
